# flot graph-label strange behavior

Tags: jquery, flot

I just start working with flot and have strange behavior.

I draw Pie graph:

```
$.plot($(control), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                radius: 3 / 4,
                label: {
                    show: true,
                    radius: 3 / 4,
                    formatter: function(label, series) {
                        return '<div class="graph-label">' + label + '<br/>' + Math.round(series.percent) + '%</div>';
                    },
                    background: {
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        color: '#000'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true
        }
    });
```

data =

```
 [{label:"CHO-180", data:12560},{label:"CHO-60", data:54355},{label:"CHO-sol", data:12187}]
```

When i draw first time graph in browser i see [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmo1L.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmo1L.png)

But then i push draw button second one, i seу a bit [different graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBNuf.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBNuf.png)
Sorry, i am newbie, and i can't to add images.

On second image added background for labels.
How to make that this background will present immediately on the first image?

Html code of labels is same in both cases.
first:

```
<span class="pieLabel" id="pieLabel1" style="position: absolute; top: 525px; left: 347px;">
<div class="graph-label">
    CHO-60
    <br>
    69%
</div>
</span>
```

second:

```
<span class="pieLabel" id="pieLabel1" style="position: absolute; top: 505px; left: 293px;">
<div class="graph-label">
    CHO-60
    <br>
    69%
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Please, specify how you invoke your drawing code.